# Wrong vertical position of index header on some pages

Tags: header-footer, indexing, authorindex

I stumbled across a totally strange behavior by using an index in our document. The vertical positioning of the headings on the first and the last page is fine, but on all intermediate pages the heading is positioned too far to the top.

Here you can see the second to last and the last page in comparison (the positioning on the last page would be the correct one):

[image: different vertical positioning of index heading]

It is kind of difficult to create a MWE which produces an index like that and I have currently no clue which package combination could cause the problem. But perhaps somebody already knows about it.

I use scrbook as the main class and use the following index definition:

```
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\indexsetup{othercode=\small}
\makeindex[%
    intoc=true,%
    options={-M indexstyle -L german-din},%
    title=Autorenregister%
]
```

I already tried inserting the package idxlayout but it didn't help.

Has anyone a good idea?

Comment: At least you should tell what document class you're using.

Comment: As stated above, I use scrbook.

Comment: OK; but I see nothing strange with a standard preamble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally figure out what happened. The KOMA-Script version (3.17a) that was shipped by my TeXlive installation had an error which was fixed by version 3.17c. I updated my TeXlive installation (now with KOMA-Script version 3.18) and the problem has been solved. :-)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I found the root cause for my trouble. I used the new package scrlayer-scrpage. If I use the (obsolete) predecessor scrpage2 instead, everything works as expected. I hadn't had more time to go into a more detailed analysis, though.

Edit: this is a MWE where this problem occurs:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage[%
  headsepline]{%
%scrpage2}          % this works as expected
scrlayer-scrpage}   % this does not work as expected

\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=Register]

\begin{document}

a\index{AA}\index{AB}\index{AC}\index{AD}\index{AE}\index{AF}\index{AG}\index{AH}\index{AI}\index{AJ}\index{AK}\index{AL}\index{AM}\index{AN}\index{AO}\index{AP}\index{AQ}\index{AR}\index{AS}\index{AT}\index{AU}\index{AV}\index{AW}\index{AX}\index{AY}\index{AZ}

b\index{BA}\index{BB}\index{BC}\index{BD}\index{BE}\index{BF}\index{BG}\index{BH}\index{BI}\index{BJ}\index{BK}\index{BL}\index{BM}\index{BN}\index{BO}\index{BP}\index{BQ}\index{BR}\index{BS}\index{BT}\index{BU}\index{BV}\index{BW}\index{BX}\index{BY}\index{BZ}

c\index{CA}\index{CB}\index{CC}\index{CD}\index{CE}\index{CF}\index{CG}\index{CH}\index{CI}\index{CJ}\index{CK}\index{CL}\index{CM}\index{CN}\index{CO}\index{CP}\index{CQ}\index{CR}\index{CS}\index{CT}\index{CU}\index{CV}\index{CW}\index{CX}\index{CY}\index{CZ}

d\index{DA}\index{DB}\index{DC}\index{DD}\index{DE}\index{DF}\index{DG}\index{DH}\index{DI}\index{DJ}\index{DK}\index{DL}\index{DM}\index{DN}\index{DO}\index{DP}\index{DQ}\index{DR}\index{DS}\index{DT}\index{DU}\index{DV}\index{DW}\index{DX}\index{DY}\index{DZ}

e\index{EA}\index{EB}\index{EC}\index{ED}\index{EE}\index{EF}\index{EG}\index{EH}\index{EI}\index{EJ}\index{EK}\index{EL}\index{EM}\index{EN}\index{EO}\index{EP}\index{EQ}\index{ER}\index{ES}\index{ET}\index{EU}\index{EV}\index{EW}\index{EX}\index{EY}\index{EZ}

f\index{FA}\index{FB}\index{FC}\index{FD}\index{FE}\index{FF}\index{FG}\index{FH}\index{FI}\index{FJ}\index{FK}\index{FL}\index{FM}\index{FN}\index{FO}\index{FP}\index{FQ}\index{FR}\index{FS}\index{FT}\index{FU}\index{FV}\index{FW}\index{FX}\index{FY}\index{FZ}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

I use the following sequence in order to compile this code:
pdflatex texindy pdflatex pdflatex
with TeX Live 2015.

The result is the following:
[image]

Comment: I see nothing strange even with the package you mention. Perhaps, if you add the relevant settings to your question…